# Communication between UITableViewDataSource and UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a tableview inside a viewcontroller and datasource of tableview is separate class, which is the best way to notify viewcontroller that some data has been added/deleted so it can add/remove rows to data ?

One idea I have is to use delegates but It will be like 
Callback from webservice to Datasource -->
Fire delegate method from datasource to viewcontroller

This is giving me feeling that I am doing something wrong, Help !!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I think this is right way.. you can use delegate and can call the methods or can use Notification

Comment: @ios I mean there will be two delegates one will return actual data and one will just notify view controller to update UI, Is it fine ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create weak property in your other class (the one with datasource) to hold reference to the view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) MyViewController *viewController;
```

and when you add/delete row just call appropriate method on your view controller, something like that:

//Row deleted

```
[self.viewController deleteRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Of course you have to add this method to your view controller.

The last step you have to do is connect view controller with your other class.
In view controller in the same place where you set up table view delegate do something like that:

```
tableView.delegate = otherClass; //<- this is the class you store table view delegate.
otherClass.viewController = self;
```

Note that this is just one way you can do this, the other one can be delegate (as you mentioned above) or blocks, notifications, etc.

// Extended

With block you have to do it like that.
In other class .h:

```
// create typedef to avoid typing all block definition
typedef void (^CompleteBlock) (NSIndexPath *indexPath);
//Declare property
@property (nonatomic, copy) CompleteBlock removeRowCompleteBlock;

// in .m file call block where you remove row:
if (self. removeRowCompleteBlock)
        self. removeRowCompleteBlock(indexPath);
```

In view controller file after you create instance of other class add remove row block:

```
tableView.delegate = otherClass; //<- this is the class you store table view delegate.
otherClass.removeRowCompleteBlock = ^(NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
    // od something
    NSLog(@"Row removed: %@", indexPath);
};
```

Comment: Thanks but wont it create circular reference ?

Comment: This is why you use weak instead of strong - to avoid circular references.

Comment: Oh yes, but actually I want to make the data source class less coupled

Comment: The weak reference avoids the retain cycle, but it does create a logical circular reference that couples the view controller and the data source in both directions which I would avoid if possible. Using a separate delegate in this case makes sense to me.

Comment: But by that way there will be two delegates one will return actual data and one will just notify view controller to update UI, Is it fine ?

Comment: If you want to make it less coupled you can use blocks instead. With blocks you will keep code to remove/add the data in view controller class and in 'the other class' you will just call appropriate block.

Comment: @UndercoverDeveloper I added example to show how to use block.

Comment: @Greg This is helpful, But How about keeping a weak reference of UITableView in that datasource class ?

Comment: You can do if you have a good reason but every datasource/delegate method provide you reference to table view as a method argument.